# MongoDB very slow $count after $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Help, I am using MongoDB 4.2.6, and writing an aggregate to obtain the number of filtered data from collections with 40000+ data. Before applying the `$count` method, I need to `$lookup` an extra collection as well.

Here is my aggregate

```
db.exams.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        schoolId: ObjectId("5d91c9ec098506001b426cb5")
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'students',
        localField: 'studentId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'student'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$student"
}, {
    $match: {
        "student.gender": 1
    }
},{
    $count: 'count'
}])
```

But it looks more than 10 seconds. I have already add indexes on every ID: `exams._id`, `students._id`, `exams.studentId`, `exams.schoolId`, `student.gender`, etc...

Can someone gives me some suggestions in order to make the query faster?

Explains:

```
{
  stages: [
    {
      $cursor: {
        query: {
          schoolId: ObjectId('5d91c9ec098506001b426cb5')
        },
        fields: {
          _id: 1
        },
        queryPlanner: {
          plannerVersion: 1,
          namespace: 'happya.exams',
          indexFilterSet: false,
          parsedQuery: {
            schoolId: {
              $eq: ObjectId('5d91c9ec098506001b426cb5')
            }
          },
          queryHash: '9533F340',
          planCacheKey: 'CE7F9610',
          winningPlan: {
            stage: 'FETCH',
            inputStage: {
              stage: 'IXSCAN',
              keyPattern: {
                schoolId: 1
              },
              indexName: 'schoolId_1',
              isMultiKey: false,
              multiKeyPaths: {
                schoolId: []
              },
              isUnique: false,
              isSparse: false,
              isPartial: false,
              indexVersion: 2,
              direction: 'forward',
              indexBounds: {
                schoolId: [
                  "[ObjectId('5d91c9ec098506001b426cb5'), ObjectId('5d91c9ec098506001b426cb5')]"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          rejectedPlans: [
            {
              stage: 'FETCH',
              inputStage: {
                stage: 'IXSCAN',
                keyPattern: {
                  schoolId: 1,
                  referenceNo: 1
                },
                indexName: 'schoolId_1_referenceNo_1',
                isMultiKey: false,
                multiKeyPaths: {
                  schoolId: [],
                  referenceNo: []
                },
                isUnique: true,
                isSparse: false,
                isPartial: false,
                indexVersion: 2,
                direction: 'forward',
                indexBounds: {
                  schoolId: [
                    "[ObjectId('5d91c9ec098506001b426cb5'), ObjectId('5d91c9ec098506001b426cb5')]"
                  ],
                  referenceNo: ['[MinKey, MaxKey]']
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'students',
        as: 'student',
        localField: 'studentId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        unwinding: {
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
        },
        matching: {
          gender: {
            $eq: 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          $const: null
        },
        count: {
          $sum: {
            $const: 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: false,
        count: true
      }
    }
  ],
  serverInfo: {
    host: 'a98010d6dcf4',
    port: 27017,
    version: '4.2.6',
    gitVersion: '20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8'
  },
  ok: 1,
  $clusterTime: {
    clusterTime: Timestamp(1597720010, 1),
    signature: {
      hash: BinData(0, '1PiNaAzDzNRrnZl/mpVJP4oneyU='),
      keyId: NumberLong('6819213090182135813')
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp(1597720010, 1)
};
```

Comment: can you try removing `$unwind`, because $match can allow direct match to array element without unwinding, i am not sure about your count, do you want it after unwinding student count or main document count?

Comment: Can you add `explain - executionStats` of the query?

Comment: @turivishal i tried removing the `$unwind` but it doesnt help

Comment: @Gibbs. explain added

Comment: Thanks. Did you try find out which stage takes more time? Hope writes are less frequent. How much memory you have to avoid too much page swaps?